# How to benchmark npm/yarn install process?

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am working on a reactjs+mobx frontend project and using es6, babel, and webpack. I am using `yarn install` to download the dependencies and does the  babel transpile work. In my project, `yarn install` takes more than 20 minutes to complete. I can say that the download only takes 1 or 2 mintues so most of them time is spent on babel or something else. Is there a way for me to figure out which part takes such a long time? My hardware is Mac Pro with 16GB memory. I don't have any performance on other open source reactjs project. It seems that only happen on my project so I am looking for a way to find the root course.

Below is my project dependencies.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^1.17.1",
    "@blueprintjs/table": "^1.14.0",
    "autobind-decorator": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^ 6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^5.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-enzyme": "^0.6.1",
    "cldr-data": "^31.0.2",
    "codemirror": "^5.27.2",
    "codemirror-colorpicker": "^1.0.8",
    "codemirror-formatting": "^1.0.0",
    "codemirror-highlight": "^1.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^3.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "d3": "^4.10.0",
    "dumpenvy": "^1.1.0",
    "d3": "^4.10.0",
    "dumpenvy": "^1.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^2.7.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^1.5.1",
    "esdoc": "^0.5.2",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eventemitter2": "^4.0.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "feathers-client": "^1.9.0",
    "feathers-primus": "^2.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "filesize": "^3.5.10",
    "globalize": "^1.2.3",
    "globalize-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.5.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "http-server": "^0.10.0",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "jest": "^20.0.4",
    "lazy-route": "^1.0.7",
    "little-loader": "^0.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "mobx": "^3.1.9",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "^4.2.11",
    "mobx-react-form": "^1.20.5",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.1",
    "mousetrap-global-bind": "^1.1.0",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.5",
    "precss": "^1.4.0",
    "prettier-standalone": "^1.3.1-0",
    "react": "~15.4.2",
    "prettier-standalone": "^1.3.1-0",
    "react": "~15.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.0.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.4.2",
    "react-codemirror": "github:SouthbankSoftware/react-codemirror",
    "react-dnd": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^2.2.4",
    "react-dom": "~15.4.2",
    "react-ga": "^2.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "next",
    "react-json-tree": "^0.10.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-select": "^1.0.0-rc.4",
    "react-shortcut": "^1.0.6",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.64",
    "react-svg-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2",
    "recharts": "^0.22.4",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.5",
    "shebang-loader": "0.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.7",
    "shebang-loader": "0.0.1",
    "shelljs": "^0.7.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "test-utils": "^1.0.18",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "uuid": "^3.0.1",
    "validatorjs": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.8.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb-uri": "^0.9.7",
    "react-json-view": "^1.10.12",
    "worker-loader": "^0.8.1"
  }
```

Below is the node version I am using:

```
$ node --version
v7.9.0
$ yarn --version
0.24.5
```

Below is the output of `yarn install`:

```
yarn run v0.24.5
$ webpack --config webpack/prod.js --optimize-minimize 
(node:7041) DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic, see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56
parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions() in the next major version of loader-utils.
Hash: 3fc20db1441aa4cbeb7c
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 1770119ms
```

Comment: Have you tried these flags?

-dd, --verbose: --loglevel verbose

-ddd: --loglevel silly

Comment: I have tried `--verbose` but doesn't help. The only thing I know from it is that the output stoped at `webpack --config webpack/prod.js --optimize-minimize ` command for quite a while. Does this mean webpack takes a long time to run?